# Buck converter or regulator

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, buck

I have a battery supply consisting of 3 AA batteries of each 1.5V.

I need an operating voltage of 3.3V.

Which choice of buck converter or regulator would be better?

My application requires 100mA of current. So are AA batteries a better choice or the conventional 9V battery?
Last time i didn't have any info regarding the current requirements now i do.
 My choices currently are AA batteries or a 9V battery .
 If there any better choices of batteries plz let me know. 
Also yes last time i received an excellent answer from swineone, but i am still confused with the best choice for the regulators. ( Whether LDO or switching regulator)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Why would you need a 9V battery to get 3.3V? What *are* your choices?

Comment: since this is even **less** specified than your previous question, not even voting to close as unclear, but as duplicate. You got two good answers, and a lot of comments, and you applied **none** of the feedback you got there. Can't help you if you can't learn from what you get.

Comment: Last time i didn't have any info regarding the current requirements now i do. My choices currently are AA batteries or a 9V battery . If there any better choices of batteries plz let me know. Also yes last time i received an excellent answer from swineone, but i am still confused with the best choice for the regulators.

Comment: If you have new information, edit your old question; don't open new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The choice on Vin beeing 4.5 (3x1.5) or 9V mostly depends on how efficient your voltage converter is. If it only "burns" the over voltage one would go with the closest input voltage that is higher then the output voltage. Also have in mind that the "burning" regulator needs a voltage that is Vout + 1V to operate correctly (Might even be higher then 1V). If you have a buck regulator you can go with any input voltage the regulator can handle. Stated in the datasheet.

In this case I would go with 3 AA batteries and any regulator you have lying around or is cheapest to buy. An TS5205 would need 600uA for the 100mA of load.

Answer (score 0):

Buck/boost off of 3x AA's, or buck from 4x AA's.  If you read the datasheet off of a [common AA battery](https://b2b-api.panasonic.eu/file_stream/pids/fileversion/3678) you will see that more than half of it's life is below 1.1V.  If you have an LDO or a buck converter you simply will miss out on most of the battery life.  Throw out the 9v idea unless you have extremely low power draw, 9v's are notorious for their internal resistance, so under any reasonable load your internal losses become very significant.